# Converting Entity Names to Entity Numbers of ISO 8859-1 Symbols

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xhtml

I need to convert entity names like 
`&nbsp; &deg; &frac14;` (as listed in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp under the ISO 8859-1 Symbols) to their corresponding entity numbers.

For example,

```
&nbsp is the entity name and its corresponding number is &#160;
&deg is the entity name and its corresponding number is &#176;
```

I tried using CGI.unescapeHTML but it only supports `&quot; &apos; &amp; &lt; &gt;`

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Please expand your question with some more background. Where and when do you need to do the conversion? Are you processing files? User input?

Comment: Not at all familiar with that library, but would it help to give the HTML a DOCTYPE that explicitly includes all the entity names? That is, the HTML 4.01 DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do the same thing myself. This is the code I came up with, hope it helps!

```
private string CleanHTML( string html )
    {
        string[] namedEntities = new string[] 
        {
            "&quot;", "&amp;", "&apos;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&nbsp;", "&iexcl;", "&cent;", "&pound;", "&curren;", "&yen;", "&brvbar;", "&sect;", "&uml;", "&copy;", "&ordf;",
            "&laquo;", "&not;", "&shy;", "&reg;", "&macr;", "&deg;", "&plusmn;", "&sup2;", "&sup3;", "&acute;", "&micro;", "&para;", "&middot;", "&cedil;", "&sup1;", "&ordm;",
            "&raquo;", "&frac14;", "&frac12;", "&frac34;", "&iquest;", "&Agrave;", "&Aacute;", "&Acirc;", "&Atilde;", "&Auml;", "&Aring;", "&AElig;", "&Ccedil;", "&Egrave;",
            "&Eacute;", "&Ecirc;", "&Euml;", "&Igrave;", "&Iacute;", "&Icirc;", "&Iuml;", "&ETH;", "&Ntilde;", "&Ograve;", "&Oacute;", "&Ocirc;", "&Otilde;", "&Ouml;", "&times;",
            "&Oslash;", "&Ugrave;", "&Uacute;", "&Ucirc;", "&Uuml;", "&Yacute;", "&THORN;", "&szlig;", "&agrave;", "&aacute;", "&acirc;", "&atilde;", "&auml;", "&aring;", "&aelig;",
            "&ccedil;", "&egrave;", "&eacute;", "&ecirc;", "&euml;", "&igrave;", "&iacute;", "&icirc;", "&iuml;", "&eth;", "&ntilde;", "&ograve;", "&oacute;", "&ocirc;", "&otilde;",
            "&ouml;", "&divide;", "&oslash;", "&ugrave;", "&uacute;", "&ucirc;", "&uuml;", "&yacute;", "&thorn;", "&yuml;", "&OElig;", "&oelig;", "&Scaron;", "&scaron;", "&Yuml;",
            "&fnof;", "&circ;", "&tilde;", "&Alpha;", "&Beta;", "&Gamma;", "&Delta;", "&Epsilon;", "&Zeta;", "&Eta;", "&Theta;", "&Iota;", "&Kappa;", "&Lambda;", "&Mu;", "&Nu;",
            "&Xi;", "&Omicron;", "&Pi;", "&Rho;", "&Sigma;", "&Tau;", "&Upsilon;", "&Phi;", "&Chi;", "&Psi;", "&Omega;", "&alpha;", "&beta;", "&gamma;", "&delta;", "&epsilon;",
            "&zeta;", "&eta;", "&theta;", "&iota;", "&kappa;", "&lambda;", "&mu;", "&nu;", "&xi;", "&omicron;", "&pi;", "&rho;", "&sigmaf;", "&sigma;", "&tau;", "&upsilon;", "&phi;",
            "&chi;", "&psi;", "&omega;", "&thetasym;", "&upsih;", "&piv;", "&ensp;", "&emsp;", "&thinsp;", "&zwnj;", "&zwj;", "&lrm;", "&rlm;", "&ndash;", "&mdash;", "&lsquo;", "&rsquo;", 
            "&ldquo;", "&rdquo;", "&bdquo;", "&dagger;", "&Dagger;", "&bull;", "&hellip;", "&permil;", "&prime;", "&Prime;", "&lsaquo;", "&rsaquo;", "&oline;", "&frasl;", "&euro;",
            "&image;", "&weierp;", "&real;", "&trade;", "&alefsym;", "&larr;", "&uarr;", "&rarr;", "&darr;", "&harr;", "&crarr;", "&lArr;", "&uArr;", "&rArr;", "&dArr;", "&hArr;",
            "&forall;", "&part;", "&exist;", "&empty;", "&nabla;", "&isin;", "&notin;", "&ni;", "&prod;", "&sum;", "&minus;", "&lowast;", "&radic;", "&prop;", "&infin;", "&ang;", "&and;",
            "&or;", "&cap;", "&cup;", "&int;", "&there4;", "&sim;", "&cong;", "&asymp;", "&ne;", "&equiv;", "&le;", "&ge;", "&sub;", "&sup;", "&nsub;", "&sube;", "&supe;", "&oplus;",
            "&otimes;", "&perp;", "&sdot;", "&vellip;", "&lceil;", "&rceil;", "&lfloor;", "&rfloor;", "&lang;", "&rang;", "&loz;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&hearts;", "&diams;", "&sbquo;",
        };

        foreach( string namedEntity in namedEntities )
        {
            char actualChar = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode( namedEntity ).ToCharArray()[0];
            html = html.Replace( namedEntity, string.Format( "&#{0};", (int)actualChar ) );
        }

        return html;
    }
```